# In a WSDL file, can the XPath of a response element be determined without invoking the service?

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, wsdl, soapui

In a WSDL file, can the XPath of a response element be determined without invoking the service? I mean just by looking at the wsdl content is it possible?

If so what tools are there which makes it easy to do this. Can this be done using SOAP UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Consume the WSDL with SoapUI, create a MockService with sample responses, usually with ? for the values in the tags.  Position your cursor on one of those.
Below the request is a multi-tab status window.  Click the XML tab, and that will reveal the XPath to the element that the cursor is on. Voila!
 [image]

Comment: This tab may only be visible in PRO version. Not sure about that, but I have Pro, and this screenshot was definitely taken with Pro.